# Printer (Epson Stylus Photo RX620) not working after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, epson

Since upgrading to 12.04 I have been unable to print. The Printer is recognised and access is available to the SD card plugged into it. Print jobs keep queuing up. In System Tools > System Settings > Printers, The printer appears and the details are:

```
Ready  "ON"  /  Location "-"  /  Model "Epson Stylus Photo RX620"  /  Supply Level   [blank]  /  Jobs  10 Active  "SHOW"  /  Default (ticked).
```

Print test page simply adds a job to the list produced when "SHOW" button is pressed. On that jobs list, "Job State" in every case is "Stopped". When a job is highlighted, the options to Pause and Resume Printing are not clickable, while that to Cancel Print Job is clickable, but has no effect.

When printing from a programme, A "Printing" warning pop-up appears on screen, But soon disappears. A job has simply been added to the job list: there is no activity at the printer whatsoever.

I use the traditional Gnome desktop, although this problem is not desktop-dependent.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my R300. Here's what I did to fix it:

1. Turn off printer.
2. Delete printer from printing dialog.
3. Turn on printer.
4. Add new printer in printing dialog

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Worked for me too. Printer added itself to the printing dialog when I turned it on (step 3), so no need to do anything in step 4 :)